# How to install zsh on git for windows

Tags: windows, bash, git

[git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows) comes with a terminal with [bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) on it.

Is it possible to install something on it, if yes How can i install zsh on this terminal?

Answer (score 4):

Install `Git for Windows SDK` more than `Git for windows`

https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/releases/tag/git-sdk-1.0.7

Then run it from **c:\git-sdk-64\git-bash.exe** (be careful if you still have "git for windows" installed, you will confuse, because they have exact same folder structure, but different files)

then install zip or others, such as tree, etc.

```
pacman -S zsh
```